# Terminate all processes before finishing the main method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I run a separate process for some logging tasks in parallel to my main process. They share some resources and I run into issues terminating the logging process before the main process finishes.

Are there any drawbacks from finishing the main Python program and keeping the subprocess? Can I be sure that it will be terminated on exiting the main program? Or would it be better to call `Process.terminate()` as my last call in the main script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the processes you're launching are `daemons`, the [main process will terminate them automatically before it exits](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

> **`daemon`**
>
> The process’s daemon flag, a Boolean value. This must be set
>   before start() is called.
>
> The initial value is inherited from the creating process.
>
> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic
>   child processes.
>
> Note that a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes.
>   Otherwise a daemonic process would leave its children orphaned if it
>   gets terminated when its parent process exits. Additionally, these are
>   not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be
>   terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

This flag is automatically set for processes created by a `multiprocessing.Pool`, but [defaults to `false` for `Process` objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L203). The parent process will try to call `join` on all non-daemon children, so if you have any of those running, they will prevent the parent from exiting  until they exit themselves.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed!